# Django REST framework - SearchFilter not filtering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using `Django 1.10` and `django-rest-framework 3.5.3`.
I would like to have a generic search query: search for a value on many fields.
I Found the [SearchFilter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) on the Docs.

I tried to add the filter backend to the ViewSet, but it seems not to be working. Any search query response with all the objects.

ViewSet:

```
from rest_framework import filters

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    filter_fields = ['username', 'email', 'is_staff', 'groups']
```

Query url:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/?search=something
```

In addition, at the docs they show that a new button "Filter" added to the django rest web page. It does not in my case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `filter_fields` use `search_fields`. `filter_fields` is for enabling filtering on specific fields, like `/users/?username=something&is_staff=True`.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your second issue and as an FYI, if you add `SearchFilter` to your `filter_backends` attribute, you have to add a `search_fields` attribute, and vise versa. Same goes for `DjangoFilterBackend`, you have to add a `filter_fields` attribute. Without them, the "Filter" button on the browsable api will not be available.

Comment: Just wanted to comment for others that I am new to django/wagtail/DRF and am setting up some API endpoints for a headless backend. I followed docs and kept looking and looking but couldn't figure out why the search on my custom model would only return all results when using `?search=`. This comment is what clued me in that I needed to add `BaseAPIEndpoint.filter_backends.append(SearchFilter)` to my extended APIEndpoint class.

Comment: @pspahn you can add to `filter_backends`  array.